# Count mysql records from this week - Monday - Sunday

Tags: php, mysql

Im currently trying to count/print out how many records I have in my database from this week (mon - sun) based on a unix timestamp.

I've had a go at the following, but just seems to print out 0 for me (so something is not right)

```
$sql = "
SELECT count(*) as totalWeek
FROM vote WHERE
WEEKOFYEAR(vote_time)=WEEKOFYEAR(CURDATE())";

$res = mysql_query($sql) or die( mysql_error());
$countWeek = mysql_result($res, 0);

echo $countWeek;
```

Comment: Please, don't use mysql_* functions in new code. They are no longer maintained and are officially deprecated. Learn about prepared statements instead, and use PDO or MySQLi - this article will help you decide which. http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/pdo-vs-mysqli-which-should-you-use/

Comment: Hi Edward - thanks a lot for putting my attention to this, will surely take a look at it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your `vote_time` column is a timestamp, you may need to convert it to a date.  Also, I think you should also modify your condition to check the current year (unless your data will not span calendar years).  So, try this:

```
SELECT count(*) as totalWeek
FROM vote 
WHERE WEEKOFYEAR(DATE(vote_time)) = WEEKOFYEAR(CURDATE())
  AND       YEAR(DATE(vote_time)) =       YEAR(CURDATE())
```

Comment: Hi Belle - your suggestion let me to the solution, adjusted it to work with by adding "from_unixtime(): "WHERE WEEKOFYEAR(DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(vote_time))) = WEEKOFYEAR(CURDATE())"

Comment: The above query will prevent mysql from using index to search, if your table is large, it will be a performance problem.

I think you should convert the begin of week to unix timestamp, then do a query with "vote_time > week_begin_time" where statement.

Answer (score 2):

if your `vote_time` is in unix time format (seconds since 1970), you will have to translate them first:

```
mysql> select WEEKOFYEAR(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp()));
+---------------------------------------------+
| WEEKOFYEAR(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp())) |
+---------------------------------------------+
|                                          21 |
+---------------------------------------------+
```

Notice the `from_unixtime` call in there

Answer (score 2):

You can use php strtotime function in your query to get all records between these two dates:

```
$start = date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime("last Monday") );
$end = date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s' );

$sql= "SELECT count(*) as totalWeek FROM vote WHERE (vote_time BETWEEN '$start' AND '$end')";
```

Comment: easy to understand example coming from not such a tech background - though ended up using bellevuebobs suggestion